# Why does function raster.Zscore in package spatialEco not work in R after installing?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, spatial-statistics

I want to calculate the z-scores for a rasterstack. I downloaded the package `spatialEco` from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatialEco/index.html

Now it is not possible to write and run the function `raster.Zscore`.

Do somebody know this problem and can help?

That is the official description of the code:

> Calculates the modified z-score for all cells in a raster
>
> Usage
>
> raster.Zscore(x, p.value = FALSE, file.name = NULL, ...)
>
> Arguments x A raster class object
>
> p.value
>
> Return p-value rather than z-score raster (FALSE/TRUE) file.nameName
> of raster written to disk...Additional arguments passed to writeRaster

If I run my code

```
raster.Zscore(rasterstack, p.value = FALSE)
```

I get following answer:

```
Fehler in raster.Zscore(rasterstack, p.value = FALSE) : 
  konnte Funktion "raster.Zscore" nicht finden 
means that--> function not found
```

Comment: apparently you didn't call the library(spatialEco) within R session

Comment: @Elio Diaz: Thanks so much :) Your answer was great! It worked!